# Creating a data frame based on the sum of the columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to calculate the mean and median of a data frame based on 'time' variable. Basically, I would rearrange the data frame based on df value. For example, if df equals 14 then in the first column I would like to have 14 rows with values of 10; if df equals 8 than in the second column I would like to have 8 rows with values of 20, and so on.

[image]

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(time = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), df = c(14, 8, 
4, 2, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Mus I managed to create df but I don't know how to continue the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uncount` to repeat the rows and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  uncount(df) %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = time) %>%
  select(-row)

#     `10`  `20`  `30`  `40`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    10    20    30    40
# 2    10    20    30    40
# 3    10    20    30    NA
# 4    10    20    30    NA
# 5    10    20    NA    NA
# 6    10    20    NA    NA
# 7    10    20    NA    NA
# 8    10    20    NA    NA
# 9    10    NA    NA    NA
#10    10    NA    NA    NA
#11    10    NA    NA    NA
#12    10    NA    NA    NA
#13    10    NA    NA    NA
#14    10    NA    NA    NA
```

---

In base R, you can use :

```
temp <- Map(rep, df$time, df$df)
sapply(temp, `[`, 1:max(lengths(temp)))
```

but this will also create empty `NA` columns for 50 and 60.